# Windows Phone Toolkit localization doesn't work

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I couldn't make WPToolkit localization work.

I've downloaded sample app from GitHub and everything Works fine. Then I created new Windows Phone Silverlight Project (targeting WP 8.0) and installed latest [WPtoolkit.Kinnara](http://www.nuget.org/packages/WPtoolkit.Kinnara/) from Nuget and added `xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"` and `<toolkit:ToggleSwitch Header="Test"/>` to the MainPage.xaml. And installed app to my phone. Even though my phone's Language and Region settings are all set to Turkish and Turkey, ToggleSwitch content was in English ("On" and "Off") instead of Turkish ("Açık" and "Kapalı").

I've tried setting `Language="tr-TR"`, setting the project neutral language to `tr-TR` and
adding `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("tr-TR")` and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("tr-TR")` in App.xaml.cs and none of these worked.

I don't want to write my own converters for these basic stuff. Am I doing something wrong or how can I make this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you missed the project supported cultures option for Turkish language. Open project settings and enable your language in the `supported cultures` list.

Comment: Thanks, setting neutral language to `(none)` and adding `Turkish (Turkey)` to supported cultures worked. But I still wonder why it doesn't work when I set neutral language to `Turkish (Turkey)` even though it listed in supported cultures.

Comment: This is how localization works. Checking supported cultures and loading strings from the selected resource.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://wpdevkvk.wordpress.com/2014/02/18/localizing-your-windows-phone-app/).. it explains how Localization can be done. Use Microsoft Multilingual Toolkit. And use the AppResources.resx file to add your text strings and then you can select the languages you want to localize and translate them using the Multilingual Toolkit editor.